# Best practice of how to distribute clients across Zookeeper cluster

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I'm using Zookeeper for distributed resource locking. I have a cluster of 7 Zookeeper instances and 7 application clients connects to them.

What is the best strategy in distribution clients across Zookeeper cluster? By distribution I mean what zoo-endpoints should be used for clients to make initial connection (I understand that on failover client may reconnect to another Zoo node automatically).

Is the one-to-one is a good strategy and why? May be all clients should connect to a single Zookeeper node? May be I should reduce number of Zookeeper nodes in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I'm using Curator library, and what I need is to just pass list of servers as connection string:

```
CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2", 1000, 1000, new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3));
```